# javascript when mapping array and sametime splice array, the result is ....?

Tags: javascript

I know code below is worst.However, I want to know why?

```js
const hello = (list) => {
    list = list.map((item, index) => {
        if (index === 3) {
            list.splice(index, 1)
        }

        return item
    })

    console.log(list)
}
hello([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

why the result is [1,2,3,4],not [1,2,3]?

---

thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the polyfill section in the `Array.prototype.map` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) on how the `map` is implemented, you would see that the array on which the `map` is called is copied initially into a variable.

A loop is then used to iterate through the elements of the copied array till it reaches the length of the array. In each iteration the callback function which you supply is called to transform each element of the array and put inside a new array which is then returned from the `map` function.

So even though you mutate the array after you call the `map` it will still refer the original data and not the new one.

If you want to skip over certain elements you should use `filter` instead of `map`.

```js
const hello = (list) => {
    list = list.filter((item, index) => {
       return index !== 3;
    })
    console.log(list)
}
hello([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: instead of using an `if` statement you could `return index !== 3`. So `=> index !== 3`

Answer (score 2):

`.map` creates a *new* array, created from the return value of each iteration over the old array. Your

```
return item
```

inside the `.map` means that the new array created will be *exactly the same* as the original array (a shallow copy).

Each element of an array will be called with `.map`'s callback even if the array gets changed in the meantime - the fact that the original `list` array has gotten `splice`d doesn't have any visible effect, because the `.map` already has a reference to every item that was in the array at the beginning, when `.map` was called.

If you had spliced item 3 *before* mapping, the result would indeed be `[1, 2, 3]`:

```js
const hello = (list) => {
  list.splice(3, 1);
  list = list.map((item, index) => {
    return item
  })
  console.log(list)
}
hello([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: splice has an effect. but with reassigning a new array it's gone